Having two text fields with two labels in input-group
I would like to have two text fields in one div withinput-group class. However, their labels in the preceding lines are not aligning vertically to the fields.
I have this code so far:
            <div class="col-sm-6 mt-3">
                <label class="form-label mb-1" for="exp-date">Exp.</label>
                <label class="form-label mb-1" for="cvc">CVC</label>
              <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control contact-form-input exp-date-select" placeholder="MM/YY" id="exp-date">
                <input type="text" class="form-control contact-form-input sec-code-select" placeholder="000" id="cvc">
              </div>
            </div>

Which gives me something like (notice location of the CVC label):


Well. I think I solved this by having a flex box combining the two labels with 50% width each:
<div class="col-sm-6 mt-3">
  <div class="d-flex">
    <label class="form-label mb-1 w-50" for="exp-date">Exp.</label>
    <label class="form-label mb-1 w-50" for="cvc">CVC</label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control contact-form-input exp-date-select" placeholder="MM/YY" id="exp-date">
    <input type="text" class="form-control contact-form-input sec-code-select" placeholder="000" id="cvc">
  </div>
</div>

